# Dual boot install (Windows after Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, dual-boot, windows

Most of the faqs/how-to for dual booting assume windows is installed with 'nix being installed in unpartitioned space.

I need to go the other way, i have wheezy installed and need to install xp, so, i'm going to resize a partion, format fat, install windows, and then ...?

does windows install over-write the MBR?
Can that be fixed (Back to grub)

I guess I don't mind reinstalling wheezy after installing xp, but that seems like a sledgehammer

references/thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows will overwrite the MBR and put their own stuff on there. You can always install grub from pretty much any [linux Live CD](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351) (or you can use a [utility Live CD](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)).

Other than that, your systems should play nice.

Comment: Rescatux does this nicely and with ease. http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/rescatuxdownloads/rescatux-stable/